# How to apply awk command on all fields except a few specific rows

Tags: awk

I have a file where every 156780th line there is a header row.

I wanted to apply awk command to every row's first column except the second column of the header rows.

Or atleast the header rows should be unaffected.

Can anyone help me to do this.

I have used the awk command as given below

```
awk 'NR>2 {printf("%10i %15.8E\n",$1,$2);}' fort.74 > fort.75
```

Answer (score 3):

The header rows will fulfill the condition `NR % 156780 == 0`.  This means that you may use

```
awk 'NR % 156780 != 0 { process non-header row }' ...
```

... or possibly

```
awk '(NR - 1) % 156780 != 0 { process non-header row }' ...
```

(as `NR` is 1 for the first row, not zero)

If you want to pass through the header lines unaffected:

```
awk '(NR - 1) % 156780 != 0 { process non-header row } (NR - 1) % 156780 == 0 { print }' ...
```

That is, just add a lone `print` action for the inverse condition of the one you use for acting on the non-header lines.

Comment: or `NR % 156780 != 1`

Comment: @ilkkachu or just `(NR - 1) % 156780`. It's a matter of taste.

Comment: Right, that too. :)

Comment: Thank You for your response. It worked but I am interested to keep the line unaffected however by giving the above command deletes all the header rows in the file.

Comment: @Parvathy Ah. I will update immediately. It was an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

how about the simple:

```
awk '(NR==1)          { header=$0; rem="we retrieve the header content";}
     ( $0 != header ) { process non header lines here ... }'
```

(you can optionnally add a "; next" in the first line, but if not it also allow you to test on a small file, for exemple one with the 5 first lines of the original file : the 2nd line shouldn't process the line if it matches the header.)